# WPF Button Define Shape and Text within Content Tag

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm reading through a WPF book, running through the examples.

Now, I'm working on some buttons.

Within the `<Button.Content> </Button.Content>` tag, I am able to define the text for the button, *or* I am able to define a shape that appears on the button face, but I don't appear to be able to do both within the same button.

Here's an example of the button with the ellipse shape on its face:

```
<Button Background="Blue">
    <Button.Content>
        <Ellipse Height="40" Width="40" Fill="Green" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Here's an example of the button with the text defined:

```
<Button Background="Red">
    <Button.Content>
        OK
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Here are the results of these two button definitions (within a WrapPanel):

[image: The Results]

When I attempt to create a button that defines both properties, using this code:

```
<Button Background="Orange">
    <Button.Content>
        OK
        <Ellipse Height="40" Width="40" Fill="Wheat" />
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

I receive an error that explains: `The property 'Content' is set more than once.`

So My question is: is it possible to combine these two button content definitions? The goal is to define a button that displays an ellipse shape and text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only set the `Content` to one element, but you could do this by placing your elements inside of one container, e.g.:

```
<Button Background="Orange">
    <Button.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse Height="40" Width="40" Fill="Wheat" />
            <TextBlock Text="OK" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in fact setting the content twice, as you are trying to place two controls.

Try using a `Stackpanel` to hold both your controls. Also put the "OK" in a `Label` or `Textbox`

**Example:**

```
<Button Background="Orange">
    <Button.Content>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="OK" Background="Red"/>
            <Ellipse Height="40" Width="40" Fill="Wheat" />
        </StackPanel>

    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: This will work, but it will *probably* not give the expected result.  You will get a single button, but the text will still be to the right of the circle.  OP most likely wants the text *within* the circle.

Comment: As @BradleyUffner hints at, the contents of the button appear next to each other instead of overlapping each other. Even still, the contents are within the button, which could be useful in some specific context.

Comment: Knowing how to choose the right layout container is one of the most important parts of learning WPF.

Comment: I had overlooked the questions specification, @Chris was quick and concise the the correct approach.